# How to connect to a server using vscode extension

Tags: connection, client-server, vscode-extensions

I wanted to start a server, possibly from Python, on local machine, loading some dictionary data into the server and allowing any local client query this server, possibly through socket connection.

Is there anything from within vscode extension framework to allow me to do this? Basically I wanted to create a command within vscode extension, then whenever I highlight a few words on the vscode editor, I wanted to check if the highlighted text is already in the server's dictionary or not. The reason being is that the dictionary is large and it takes time to load, so if it is already loaded in the memory, querying only action should be much quicker.

Can you tell me if this is possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [LSP](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/) framework that MS developed for this kind of IDE functionality. It's well integrated with VS code extensions and well documented: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide.

Comment: Thank you ever so much. I had thought nobody will answer anyway. Thank you. I will take a good look at it.

Comment: I have taken some times to watch some videos on YouTube regarding LSP, but I think this is more of the Compiling Techniques, Lexical Analysis then what I am setting out to do. I already have the dictionary data in PO (gettext) format and I had created some code in Python to load the data as a dictionary, is there a way creating a server and running it in the background where dictionary is loaded, possibly using Python, I can use vscode to query the server, possibly using socket communications. Does anyone know how this could be achieved?

Comment: I just post my personal answer here incase someone is searching solutions for the same problem. I ended up using fastAPI ``python -m pip install fastapi, uvicorn`` and create a HTTP server on local machine, then in the vscode typescript extension import HTTP and use ``http.get(url, callback).end();`` to interact with the python server.